# Debugging inline assembly in C++ code in Visual Studio 2022 is broken

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging, inline-assembly

We are having issues with debugging inline assembly code in Visual Studio 2022 Community. It worked fine in previous versions, such as 2017, 2019. Even though the optimizations are disabled, debuggable assembly is set to Yes, support just my code debugging is set to No, Debug Information format is set to Program Database /Zi, Basic Runtime Checks are set to Default...

...the debugger incorrectly shows the current line, when stepping over an inline assembly code. It can be clearly seen when Debug Window Disassembly is shown - instructions are not detected properly to align to the source code. Thus when debugging without disassembly, debugger shows incorrect lines, and - breakpoints do not work as they are not detected at proper instructions.

I was wondering if anyone has a hint for any other options that we could try to switch to get this working. We've been fighting this a few months, and Microsoft Support requires you to pay 149 Eur just to *file a bug*.

[image]

adding debug windows modules and output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking at Debug/Windows/Modules?  Is there anything interesting about the symbol information there?  How about Debug/Windows/Output?  And it's obvious, but I'll also ask if you've tried a clean build?  Make sure all obj/pdb files are gone (esp the one for the asm file) just to be sure, then read thru the build output carefully for clues.  Do you explicitly see the file with the asm getting rebuilt?

Comment: Thanks @DavidWohlferd for the hints. I have added the two debug windows in the post above, not sure what to look for there. Yes, completely clean. I have uploaded the project at https://kempelen.dai.fmph.uniba.sk/files/ASM.zip if anyone likes to check.

Comment: So, the good news it that it has nothing to do with source/obj/pdb being out out alignment.  That's the bad news too.  Apparently they've mucked something up wrt to labels.  If there's a simple way around it, I'm not seeing it.  Is inline asm a requirement?  Or can you do straight asm (ie in a separate .asm file) instead?

Comment: We use it in a course, where inline asm is used. For its simplicity (1st year students) and also to demonstrate how cdecl notation deals with EBP, etc. Computers in the terminal room have older versions, but students installed latest on their personal computers, and ran into these difficulties. It was fun when they came to me to ask for help, and I could not properly debug their code. Fortunately in the disassembly window, tracing over the underlying instructions is "ok", so it is possible to debug that way.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of inline asm myself.  There are hidden costs as the c compiler attempts to work around what you have written.  Then there's the whole "don't support x64" thing.    Showing how cdecl/parameter passing works can still be done with pure asm.  Still, perhaps it's a good fit for what you need.  As for "charging to file a bug," there's always [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem).  No fee required (but no response guaranteed either).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the button that lead me to that 149 Eur option... Regardless whether I login with organization or personal Microsoft account (and after having to enter the credentials about 4 times...) It may be different in other countries though.

Comment: Since they aren't charging me anything, I went ahead and [opened](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/inline-asm-writes-incorrect-line-number/10074759) one for you.  Whether anything will come of it remains to be seen.  If it'll let you (without charging you for it), you could upvote.  That seems to influence what gets attention.

Comment: Well, I've done all I can: Easy-to-understand sample, clearly incorrect behavior, documented precisely where things are going wrong, found what version the problem was introduced in.  34 upvotes isn't too bad (if these were all from your students, don't ever tell me). Lin Gao says it's been sent to the developers, but it's never clear what that means.  They could be working on it as we speak, or they could already have decided to never fix it.  If we don't hear anything for a while, I may see if I can find more bugs that complain about this.  The damage happened Nov 2020, so it seems likely.

Comment: Yes, they are. They got 1% credit to the course. :-)
It is a nice example of bug report. They have to learn how that works. They are just 1st year students. I should now pay you for teaching them in this way. And if MS would do their part, they would also see that it pays off to report the issues. Let's see. It's really dirty bug and makes debugging inline assembly without disassembly window open a useless feature. In fact, inline assembly support is poor - editor permanently breaks formatting of labels as it believes it is a c++ code. One student figured adding semicolons helps,but it's ugly

Comment: Learning to write good bug reports is an important skill which every programmer will need eventually. I'm glad you're teaching it as many people are quite bad at it.  Arguably a really good bug report is one that gets things fixed, so we don't really know how good mine is yet.  Still, you do the best you can and hope.  "pay" Hey, I got 34 upvotes.  That's a lot for me.  Next time I'm in Slovakia, you can buy me a lemonade.

Comment: Speaking of workarounds, maybe download the [6.7.28 build tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history) and build your code from the command line (`cl.exe /Zi asm3.cpp`). Seems to be debuggable from vs2022's debugger (File/Open Project against exe). Horrible hack, but if you can't download older VS versions, at least it's something.  In fact, you can probably change the Properties/Item type to "Custom build tool" and point to the 6.7.28 tools.  Still awkward, but slightly less horrible.  That's if I can't convince you to go with straight asm instead of inline...

Comment: I have to confess, I'd about given up hope.  But it turns out, [they fixed it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/inline-asm-writes-incorrect-line-number/10074759#T-N10281790).  I'm not sure when "the next major VS update" is.  Hopefully they don't mean VS2023/24, but still: Found and fixed.

Comment: And now it looks like they've released a version that includes the fix.  I just downloaded 17.6.0, and it appears to be fixed.  Can you confirm?

Comment: Many thanks David for taking care of all this! I confirm it now works as expected.